# Unknown log level for Akka stdout

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

On my play project I'm getting `unknown akka.stdout-loglevel WARNING` error. What does this mean? Could this be about Turkish locale?

Answer (score 2):

Put `-Duser.language=en` in your `~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING is a valid loglevel in akka Logging.It works with both std and external loggers. You have probably got spaces after WARNING as it seems. like "WARNING "

Comment: I'm not setting that anywhere

Comment: ok. check logging level in application.conf. 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/AkkaCore